# Solve $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I think this integral does not converge. I want to  estimate downward the integral, but don't know how to.

Comment: Substitute $u = \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: $-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 (u)}{u^2}\mathrm{d}u$ and then?

Comment: And then you see that the integral is finite. (And you have a sign error.)

Comment: http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cleft%20%7C%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20%5E2%28u%29%7D%7Bu%5E2%7D%20%5Cright%20%7C%3C%5Cleft%20%7C%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20%28u%29%7D%7Bu%7D%20%5Cright%20%7C%3C%5Cleft%20%7C%20%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%5Csqrt%7B%7Bu%7D%7D%20%5Cright%20%7C is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Set $u=1/x$, then $du=-dx/x^2$, and
$$
\int_0^\infty \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2u\,du}{u^2},
$$
which converges, as 
$$
\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2}\le \max\left\{\frac{1}{u^2},1\right\}.
$$

**Note.** Using residue calculus one could obtain that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2u\,du}{u^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Using Daniel's suggestion, you are led to evaluate
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}dx
$$
which is equal to 
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
by an integration by parts applied on $[\epsilon,M]$ (then $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, $M \rightarrow \infty.$)